# readLines to scrape website runs in RStudio, not in R

Tags: r, rstudio

This line runs in RStudio fine:

```
a <- readLines("https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/enforcement/med-licensed-facilities")
```

But it does not run in R.

R says:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : unsupported URL scheme
```

I need this to run in batch mode, which is why I need it in R. It used to run fine, but I've upgraded my computer, R is now 64 bit, and it doesn't work.

I thought it might be an http vs https problem, because:

```
readLines("http://www.r-project.org/")
```

Works in both, but:

```
readLines("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl")
```

Also works in both R and RStudio.

Comment: `readLines` does not support `https` It's documented in the help file

Comment: It doesn't run in RStudio, it runs in R through RStudio.

Comment: @RichardScriven - d'oh! Thanks, but it's weird that it does run in RStudio.

Comment: @Pascal - thanks, but why does it succeed when run through RStudio?

Comment: It doesn't work me, neither in R nor R via RStudio, for the reason @RichardScriven pointed out.

Comment: I'd suggest `getURL()` from the `RCurl` package

Comment: @RichardScriven, thanks. (If you want to add your two comments as an answer, I think it's the best one.)

Comment: I have exactly the same situation - `readLines` with `https` works fine in RStudio, but it doesn't in R